# How to select a record with looping condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a table with set of tasks as below. I would like to find out which WOID has all the work tasks completed ( T01,T02,T03) and with any of the admin tasks not completed( T04, T05) which means Tasks T01,T02 & T02 must be in complete state and either Task T04 or T05 in a non complete state. My query would return result WOID W02 as it matches the criteria. I'm having hard time to have above logics in my query.

| Task ID | Status | WOID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | Complete | W01 |
| T02 | Pending | W01 |
| T03 | Complete | W01 |
| T04 | Pending | W01 |
| T05 | Pending | W01 |
| T01 | Complete | W02 |
| T02 | Complete | W02 |
| T03 | Complete | W02 |
| T04 | Complete | W02 |
| T05 | Pending | W02 |

First I tried to find the WOID with all completed tasks then join with another sub query to find out the non completed admin tasks but not getting the expected results. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<code>
select a.WOID from
( select a.TASKID,a.WOID,a.STATUS,row_number()over 
   (partition by a.TASKSID order by a.TASKSID ,a.WOID,a.STATUS )rno  from Task a
Left join Task b on a.TASKSID= b.TASKSID) a 
where rno=1
and  a.status='COMPLETE' and a.TASKSID not in ('T04','T05') </code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you don't want looping here, you're writing SQL. Some simple conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause seems to be what you're after:

```sql
SELECT WOID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY WOID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TaskID IN ('T01','T02','T03') AND Status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) = 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN TaskID IN ('T04','T05') AND Status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to find out which WOID has all the work tasks completed ( T01,T02,T03) and with any of the admin tasks not completed( T04, T05)

I would express this as:

```
SELECT WOID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY WOID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TaskID IN ('T01', 'T02', 'T03') AND Status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN TaskID IN ('T04', 'T05') AND Status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

You can then simplify this to:

```
SELECT WOID
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE Status = 'Complete'
GROUP BY WOID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TaskID IN ('T01', 'T02', 'T03') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN TaskID IN ('T04', 'T05') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Both of these assume that you don't have duplicates.